# Does Tesseract correct spelling (UB Mannheim, Windows installation)?

Tags: tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm using Tesseract to perform ocr tasks.

Can someone confirm if tesseract has an LSTM module for auto-post-ocr spell correction? And if yes, what did I do wrong so it's not triggered?

It appears it does have this module (e.g. see slide 4 in first link):

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/docs/blob/master/das_tutorial2016/2ArchitectureAndDataStructures.pdf

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/4.0-with-LSTM

However, many example outputs give me misspelled words such as **ambuiatory**/**ambutatory** for **ambulatory**, and sometimes **informat** for **information**. This seems that tesseract picked the characters with highest likelihood, assembled them, but didn't perform any post-ocr processing.

Here's how I'm using tesseract

I followed the UB Mannheim installation:
https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki

and pytesseract through pip install:
https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/

Here's my sample codes (sorry my image is internal so cannot be posted):

```
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract'
pth_test = r'C:\Users\username\image_path_continues'
print( pytesseract.image_to_string(pth_test, lang = 'eng') )
```